# Amplify build fails when adding an API

Tags: angular, aws-api-gateway, aws-amplify

I have an angular application running on AWS Amplify. I would like to create an API for the app that will trigger lambda functions for corresponding routes. Prior to adding an API using the `amplify add api` cli command, the build works fine and the application is deployed with no issues. When I add an API & function using the cli command and then immediately push to my repo, the build fails with a `Received error [Error: Command failed with ENOENT: npm.cmd install --no-bin-links --production spawn npm.cmd ENOENT] running command [npm.cmd install --no-bin-links --production]`. Below are how I configured the api and the error I received in more detail

```
$ amplify add api
√ Provide a friendly name for your resource to be used as a label for this category in the project: · api123     

√ Provide a path (e.g., /book/{isbn}): · /items     
√ Choose a Lambda source · Create a new Lambda function
? Provide an AWS Lambda function name: checkout
? Choose the runtime that you want to use: NodeJS
? Choose the function template that you want to use: Serverless ExpressJS function (Integration with API Gateway)



✅ Available advanced settings:
- Resource access permissions
- Scheduled recurring invocation
- Lambda layers configuration
- Environment variables configuration
- Secret values configuration

? Do you want to configure advanced settings? Yes
? Do you want to access other resources in this project from your Lambda function? No
? Do you want to invoke this function on a recurring schedule? No
? Do you want to enable Lambda layers for this function? No
? Do you want to configure environment variables for this function? No   
? Do you want to configure secret values this function can access? Yes    
? Enter a secret name (this is the key used to look up the secret value): secret_key
? Enter the value for secret_key: [hidden]
? What do you want to do? I'm done
√ Choose the package manager that you want to use: · NPM
Use the AWS SSM GetParameter API to retrieve secrets in your Lambda function.
More information can be found here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/APIReference/API_GetParameter.html
? Do you want to edit the local lambda function now? No
✅ Successfully added resource checkout locally.

✅ Next steps:
Check out sample function code generated in <project-dir>/amplify/backend/function/checkout/src
"amplify function build" builds all of your functions currently in the project
"amplify mock function <functionName>" runs your function locally
To access AWS resources outside of this Amplify app, edit the \amplify\backend\function\checkout\custom-policies.json
"amplify push" builds all of your local backend resources and provisions them in the cloud
"amplify publish" builds all of your local backend and front-end resources (if you added hosting category) and provisions them in the cloud
✅ Succesfully added the Lambda function locally
√ Restrict API access? (Y/n) · no
√ Do you want to add another path? (y/N) · no
✅ Successfully added resource api123 locally
```

[image: build log]

I have tried reconfiguring the project to see if the build or start commands were the issue but that didn't seem to work. I have also tried deleting the amplify folder and reexecuting `amplify pull --appId [appId] --envName [envName]` but that also does not seem to fix the problem.